# Как правильно написать слово междувахтовый

Tags: словообразование

Слитно или раздельно правильно
междувахтовый или между вахтовый отдых?

межвахтовый - можно написать или это разговорный вариант?

Answer (score 1):

Сабина, "междувахтовый" - однозначно слитно.
Проблема, правда, в том, что в "подручных" словарях слово не фиксируется. 
Но по общему правилу "между" с прилагательными (т. е. когда не предлог) пишется слитно.
Точно так же есть вполне приставка "меж" с тем же занчением, её использование совсем не делает общелитературное слово разговорным.

Я бы субъективно предпочел именно такой вариант написания - межвахтовый.

Кстати, разговорный оттенок совсем не запрещает написание слова, это вещи совсем не противопоставляются. Но это и не актуально в нашем случае, ибо слово "межвахтовый" вряд ли разговорное.